# javascript module that is using jquery loaded before jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have javascript module which should only be interpreted only after jquery is loaded

example

```
<script src=myApp.js></script>
<script src=jQuery.js></script>
```

- myApp.js is using jQuery.
- script include sequence has to be like provided before

How to do this? As i can't flip them and do

```
<script src=jQuery.js></script>
<script src=myApp.js></script>
```

The reason for this is that I have a layout.html that has some scripts which uses jquery,
but each other view which inherits layout.html (etc. index.html) is using different version of jquery, so i want jquery to be unique per page.

Comment: hmm... did you forget to ask a question?

Comment: I appreciate that English is not your first language, but what do you want us to help with?

Comment: If you can't modify the sequence, are you also unable to modify the tag itself? if you add `defer` to the first script, it should run after the 2nd in all browsers that support defer. Otherwise, you'll have to use some hackish solution with `setInterval` or `setTimeout`. Why exacty can't you just move your app to after jquery?

Comment: @KevinB your answer was actually what i needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app, you could check for the existance of jQuery on a timer, and then do your main loop...

```
var sanity = 1000 // will only run 1000 times
function checkJquery(){
    if(typeof jQuery == 'undefined' && sanity--){
        setTimeout(checkJquery,100) // check again after 1/10th of a second
    } else { // jQuery has loaded!
        main() // run the main script
    }
}
setTimeout(checkJquery,100)

function main(){
    // your module code
}
```

Comment: I love the fact that you're implicitly testing for, and using, insanity as a sanity-check. =D

Comment: (I'm sorry, I *really* hadn't intended it to be a criticism, positive or negative; it really was just something that made me grin...but, strictly-speaking, it probably makes more sense to decreasing-insanity , and sanity itself, as the sanity-check. Less-funny though...)

Comment: Thank you. This is actually what I want. But i think its a bit hacky. Is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: @ArtūrasZakrevskis it is hacky, the clean solution is to rearrange the HTML. Web stuff works in layers, you start with content, add style, and then finally interactivity - HTML/CSS/JS. You should be able to control all of the code. If you can not change your HTML, it shows a weakness in your set-up, which should be addressed, otherwise you end up with hacky code like this!

Answer (score 0):

flip them:

```
<script src=jQuery.js></script>
<script src=myApp.js></script>
```

javascript loads sequentially, and remember jquery is a javascript library, so you need to load it BEFORE you use it.

Answer (score -1):

Why wouldn't you just put jQuery as the first include? Since it depends on nothing else?

Try doing

```
<script src=jQuery.js></script>
<script src=myApp.js></script>
```